# Implementing a decoding algorithm for directed figure codes

Tags: algorithms, encoding-scheme

I have to implement algorithm, where definitions, input and output of program go as follows:

> $Σ$ - finite, non-empty alphabet
>
> A
>   *translation*
>   in
>   $Z^2$
>   by vector
>   $u
> = (
> u_x
> , u_y
> )
> ∈
> Z^2$
>   will be denoted by
>   $τ_u$
>   ,
>
> $τ_
> u
> :
> Z^
> 2
> ∋
> (
> x, y
> )
> →
> (
> x
> +
> u_x
> , y
> +
> u
> _y
> )
> ∈
> Z
> ^2
> .$
>
> Definition 1 (Directed Figure): Let $D\subset Z^2$be finite and connected, $b,e\in D$, $b,e$ don't necessary have label,  and $l:D→Σ$
>   . A quadruple$f = (D, b, e, l)$ is called a directed figure (over $Σ$) with:
>
> domain $dom (f) = D$ ,
>
> start point begin $(f) = b$,
>
> end point $end(f)= e$,
>
> labelling function  $label(f)= l$.
>
> Example of Directed Figure:
>
> $(
> [
> (0
> ,
> 0)
> ,
> (1
> ,
> 0)
> ,
> (1
> ,
> 1)
> ]
> ,
> (0
> ,
> 0)
> ,
> (1
> ,
> 2)
> ,
> [
> (0
> ,
> 0)
> →
> a,
> (1
> ,
> 0)
> →
> b,
> (1
> ,
> 1)
> →
> c
> ]
> )$
>
> The set of all directed figures over $Σ$ is denoted by $Σ^⋄$
>
> Definition 2 (Catenation): Let $x= (D_x, b_x, e_x, l_x)$ and $y= (D_y, b_y, e_y, l_y)$be directed figures. Catenation of $x$ and $y$ with respect to mamerging function $m: Σ×Σ→Σ$ is defined as $x◦_m y = (D_x∪τ_{x_e−y_b}(D_y), b_x, τ_{x_e−y_b}(e_y), l)$
>
> where
>
> $l(z) = l_x(z)$  for $z∈D_x \setminus τ_{x_e−y_b}(D_y)$,
>
> $l(z) = τ_{x_e−y_b}(l_y)(z)$ for $ z∈τ_{x_e−y_b}(D_y)\setminus D_x$,
>
> $l(z) = m(l_x(z), τ_{x_e−y_b}(l_y)(z))$ for $z∈D_x∩τ_{x_e−y_b}(D_y).$
>
> Definition 3 (Code)
>   $X
> ⊆
> Σ
> {^⋄_
> m}$
>   is a
>   code
>   if for any
>   $x
> _1
> , . . . , x
> _k
> , y
> _1
> , . . . , y
> _l
> ∈
> X$
>   the equality
>   $x_
> 1
> ◦_
> m
> . . .
> ◦_
> m
> x_k
> =
> y_
> 1
> ◦_
> m
> . . .
> ◦_
> m
> y_
> l$
>   implies
>   $k
> =
> l$
>   and
>   $x_
> i
> =
> y_
> i$
>   for each
>   i
>   $∈{
> 1
> , . . . , k
> }$
>   .
>
> Input:
>
> 1. Code,
> 2. Catenation of $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ with respect to a merging function, where $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ belong to a code  (uniquely decodable)
> 3. merging function
>      $m
>    : Σ
>    ×
>    Σ
>    →
>    Σ$
>
> Output: 
>   $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$

The definitions of directed figure, catenation, and code are in the paper from https://dmtcs.episciences.org/455/pdf by Michal Kolarz and Wlodzimierz Moczurad. (pages 3,4,5, respectively)

My first task was to implement a catenation of directed figures which was easy, now I have to do similar problem, but backwards.
I thought about this problem for two days, but nothing really comes to my mind. 
I had a few ideas but when I've thought about them deeper, they had some flaws in them.
Any ideas about how this algorithms should look like would be appreciated.

Comment: Given that it is non-trivial to determine whether your setup is uniquely decodable, I suspect that the problem is somewhat difficult, and you might have to use ideas from the paper. I think this question is a bit too elaborate for this site, but perhaps someone else will be willing to help you with your homework.

Comment: I've forgot to put the definition of Code . My setup is uniquely decodable, I will add this information.